# Communicating between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is an screenshot from my app.

[image]

This screen is a fragment that has sliding tabs layout. It will hold another fragment that will show data in listview. The problem is, in order to load data the value selected from the spinner need to pass within the fragment in tab. I am not getting idea how to do this. One approach would be the tab fragment would implement a callback and within that callback data should be loaded. But I am not getting how to register that callback in `onItemSelected` of spinner.

Note: All fragments within the tab will show data in listview only, so I have created a common fragment.

This is my code so far:
**Fragment for the screenshot**

```
public class BuyListingFragment2 extends BaseFragment {
private Context ctx;
private Spinner vehicle_type;
private ArrayList<ListingTabModel> mListingTabs = new ArrayList<ListingTabModel>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> vehicleTypeSpinnerlist;
private int spinnerPosition;
private SlidingTabLayout sliding_tabs;
private BuyListingPagerAdapter buyListingPagerAdapter;

public static BuyListingFragment2 newInstance(String category,
        int position, String preselectedFilters) {
    BuyListingFragment2 fragment = new BuyListingFragment2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("vehicle_type", category);
    args.putInt("spinner_position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public BuyListingFragment2() {

}   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.vehicleType = getArguments().getString("vehicle_type");
    this.selectedVehicle = this.vehicleType;
    this.spinnerPosition = getArguments().getInt("spinner_position");

    ArrayList<CategoryType> vehicleTypeList = RegistrationResponse
            .getInstance().getVehicleTypeList();
    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vehicleTypeList);
    buyListingPagerAdapter = new BuyListingPagerAdapter(
            getChildFragmentManager(), mListingTabs);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ctx = getActivity();
    vehicle_type = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_type);
    vehicle_type.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    vehicle_type.setSelection(spinnerPosition, false);
    if (mListingTabs.isEmpty()) {
        String[] tabNames = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.listing_tab_names);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabNames.length; i++) {
            String tabName = tabNames[i];
            ListingTabModel mListingTabModel = new ListingTabModel();
            mListingTabModel.setTagName(tabName);
            mListingTabs.add(mListingTabModel);
        }
    }
    buyListingPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listing_layout_viewpager = (ViewPager) view
            .findViewById(R.id.listing_layout_viewpager);
    listing_layout_viewpager.setAdapter(buyListingPagerAdapter);
    sliding_tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    sliding_tabs.setViewPager(listing_layout_viewpager);
    vehicle_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            spinnerPosition = position;
            //How to register listener here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}   
}
```

**Common Fragment inside Tab**

```
public class ListingFragment extends BaseFragment implements
    OnSpinnerDataSelected {
private InfiniteListView mListView;
private BuyListingListAdapter buyListingAadapter;
private RobotoLightTextView emptyMessage;
private int currentPageNumber = 1;
private int totalPages;
private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
private int apiCallCount = 0;
private Context ctx;
private String vehicleType;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
public ListingFragment() {
}

public static ListingFragment newInstance(ListingTabModel mListingTabModel) {
    ListingFragment mFragment = new ListingFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // bundle.putBoolean("is_grid_view", mListingTabModel.isShowGridView());
    // bundle.putString("vehicle_type", mListingTabModel.getVehicleType());
    mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return mFragment;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ctx = getActivity();
    emptyMessage = (RobotoLightTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.empty_message);
    mListView = (InfiniteListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstVw_buy);

    boolean isGrid = getArguments().getBoolean("is_grid_view");

    vehicleType = getArguments().getString("vehicle_type");

    buyListingAadapter = new BuyListingListAdapter(ctx,
            mVehicleListingList, isGrid);
    mListView.setAdapter(buyListingAadapter);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(ctx);
}

@Override
public int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.layout_messages;
}
@Override
public void onSpinnerDataSelected(String vehicleCategory) {
    // TODO: fetch listing data
}
}
```

**Callback implemented by the ListingFragment**

```
public interface OnSpinnerDataSelected {
        void onSpinnerDataSelected(String vehicleCategory);
}
```

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

```
public class BuyListingPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<ListingTabModel> mFragmentsList;

    public BuyListingPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<ListingTabModel> mFragmentsList) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragmentsList = mFragmentsList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        ListingFragment listingFragment = ListingFragment
                .newInstance(mFragmentsList.get(index));
        return listingFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String tagName = mFragmentsList.get(position).getTagName();
        tagName = tagName.replace("_", " ");
        return tagName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return object == view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the Activity to communicate between fragment or a Bus Manager like https://github.com/square/otto

Comment: @HugoGresse I don't want to use any library. My tabbed fragment is already implementing the listener. But now I am not getting how to invoke the callback `onItemSelected` of spinner.

Comment: in the fragment that display the spinner, register your spiner listener. When user select the item of the spinner,, prevent `getActivity()` (with correct cast) that a spinner item as been selected). Then when the other fragment need that information, it will call `getActivity().getSpinnerSelectedItem` (eg) or if the fragment is already here, you can call the registered listener of your activity with `mExternalSpinnerListener.onSpinnerSelected` (eg)

Comment: So basically, the activity should implement the listener. Am I right?. My app has only one ativity. Currently, the fragment within the tab is implementing that listener.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain?

Comment: I've just upvote you ;). Will draw a simple schema to explain my mind soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using one activity and multiple fragments, I suggest to let the **Fragment manage the UI** and use the Activity has a controller/model.

**Workflow** for a spinner to communicate with other fragments :

1. Register the spinner listener in Frag1
2. Register a data listener from Frag2 in Activity
3. OnItemSelected from Frag1 prevent Activity from the Spinner value change
4. Activity received the spinner change value
5. Activity call Frag2 listener to prevent Frag2 of the spinner change
6. Frag2 receive spinner change, do your stuff

#### Here is a litle schema

[image: activity/fragment communication with spinner]

Answer (score 2):

I would base everything on an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). IMHO, Fragments were meant to be decoupled from hosting activities and such, but all the interfaces and callbacks end up creating spaghetti code. Otto lets you post event on a common bus -- the receiver doesn't need to be tied to the sender via some listener/callback mechanism. Plus, it works great in conjunction with dependency injection, see [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

Comment: Completely agreed, But due to some constraints I don't want to use event bus for now. I have used it in past and it really makes our job simple.